# Full content iframe in bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to embed an iframe of an appointment scheduling frontend in my page. The scheduling program is responsive and when embedding in my page the width is fine. The problem is the frame height is very small. I have tried changing the css everyway I can think of. I have tried multiple different css tricks to no avail. Is this possible with css alone? I have access to both servers. Below is a picture of what I have so far. If the content was full height it would be perfect.

I have read multiple posts on stackoverflow and the web. I tried everything from this site, no go.  https://benmarshall.me/responsive-iframes/ 
Here is an image of what I have now: 
[image: 1]

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
<iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://xxx" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

I want the iframe to be the full height of iframe content.
Any help/direction would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to handle the content loaded event and then resize your iframe height. As far as I know this is not achievable with css alone.

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to make this work using CSS. I had a responsive style-sheet that was overriding my css class. I added the below code and it is working for me. Fortunately I have access to the iframe content and know the height that I needed. In order for this to work this way the iframe content must be responsive already. I used the following code and things are working for me. Wish I hadn't spent so much time on something so simple, but happy I got it going.

```
.embed-responsive-full {
    padding-top: 100%;
    height: 720px;
}
```